# MSDeploy, IIS 6, Is the Deploy context menu available

Tags: iis-6, msdeploy

When using IIS6, should the 'Deploy' context menu item be available when right clicking on a web site?

I've installed the Web Deploy 2.1 (web installation tool) and rebooted but still it doesn't show.  Maybe it doesn't show, and you just use the Web Deploy command line instead?

Any information appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, The "deploy" context menu is only available in IIS 7 and 7.5. You'll have to do things via command line.

If you want to migrate from iis6 to iis7 you can follow the instructions here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/427/migrate-a-web-site-from-iis-60-to-iis-7/ Note part 3 which goes into the actual web deploy commands.

> Part 3 – Migrate your site to the
>   target by using a package file
>
> 1. Always make a backup of the destination server. Even if you are
>      just testing, it allows you to easily
>      restore the state of your server.
>
>    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add backup “PreWebDeploy”
> 2. Run the following command on the source server to create a package
>      (compressed) file of the server:
>
>    msdeploy -verb:sync  -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 -dest:package=c:\Site1.zip > WebDeployPackage.log
> 3. Copy the package file to the destination server.
> 4. Run the following command on the destination server to validate what
>      would happen if a sync operation were
>      run:
>
>    msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\Site1.zip -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 -whatif > WebDeploySync.log
> 5. After verifying the output, run the same command again without the whatif
>      flag:
>
>    msdeploy -verb:sync -source:package=c:\Site1.zip -dest:metakey=lm/w3svc/1 > WebDeploySync.log